# vba setting wksheet variable

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm trying to set a variable for a worksheet on a 2nd workbook (Trowing an object error on the last line, stamWs). I've already got a variable for both workbooks. My code looks as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kopie()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

Dim stam, comp As String
Dim PathOnly, ijk, FileOnly As String
Dim ijkWs, stamWs As Worksheets

ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties
Set ijkWs = ActiveSheet

    Workbooks.Open stam
Set stamWs = stam.Sheets("stambestand")
```

I've tried referencing active worksheet, no luck and a host of other references to worksheets/workbook combinations. Your input is greatly appreciated.

Update: Tanks for the input guys. I've changed sheets to sheet in the declaration part and opened the workbook before setting the variable sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting up a workbook object when you are opening the workbook, and using that to create your worksheet object.

```
Dim newWB as WorkBook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Open(stam)
Set stamWs = newWB.WorkSheets("stambestand")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Worksheet` type not `Worksheets`.

```
Dim ijkWs, stamWs As Worksheet
```

But here unintuitively only `stamWs` if of type `Worksheet`, instead always use the form:

```
Dim ijkWs As Worksheet, stamWs As Worksheet.
```

This applies to all your `Dim`s.

You need to store the opened workbook then get the sheet, `stam` is just a *string* so has no properties so `stam.Sheets` is not correct.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(stam)
Set stamWs = wb.Sheets("stambestand")
```

I also think you change to:

```
stam = PathOnly & StBestand
comp = PathOnly & Competenties
```

else you will get a double `\` an an invalid path if the current book is not saved anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Your anwser is very useful as well. However I can only mark one as acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing around with names and using PathOnly variable, just use ThisWorkbook.Path method. Much faster and easier, also eliminates the possibility of an error.
Probably you already have a backslash in the end of the PathOnly variable, so your stam variable looks like this - "workbook_path\\Stambestand.xlsm" and that may be the cause of your problems.

Try

```
stam = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & StBestand
```